# How to delete all values in a column with lowercase

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset I am working on and it has a description column where items for sale are represented in uppercase and expenses are represented in lowercase. I am trying to drop all rows with lower case.

Sample data :

```
invoiceid   description(string datatype)
100         WHITE METAL LANTERN
200         post expenses
300         BLACK WIRE
```

what I want to achieve

```
invoiceid   description
100         WHITE METAL LANTERN
300         BLACK WIRE
```

I tried using the following codes but I kept getting errors

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import upper, lower col

df4 = df3.where(col('Description').islower())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way; extract the caps into a column. The lower case will return blank. Filter out the blanks and drop the extract column to clean df

```
 df.withColumn('filt', regexp_extract('description(string datatype)','[A-Z]+', 0)).filter("filt != ''").drop('filt').show()

+---------+----------------------------+
|invoiceid|description(string datatype)|
+---------+----------------------------+
|      100|         WHITE METAL LANTERN|
|      300|                  BLACK WIRE|
+---------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: @lee, was this helpful or needed something else done?

Comment: Thanks alot for the response... will test it shortly.

Comment: Ok, lets know how you go